# How to stream video from the RPi to a web browser in realtime?

Tags: python, camera

How to stream  video from the RPi to a web browser in realtime?
I need help please for my surveillance robot

Comment: the crying and begging emojis are an instant turn-off and very annoying

Comment: See [Tour](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/tour) to see how this site works
and [How do I ask a good question?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I would imagine ffmpeg and nginx would be involved - and the ability to create a web page

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which particular version of the Raspberry Pi and camera you are using.

However, this is the generic method of real-time  video streaming with the Raspberry Pi.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7uFYwxkFVYo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qs3KhLDUBmk

Answer (score 0):

There are several products that aim to do this. You could have a look at (in no particular order):

> MotionEye https://github.com/motioneye-project/motioneye/wiki
>
> Shinobi https://shinobi.video/
>
> Home Assistant https://www.home-assistant.io/ (a lot more than just
> video).

I'm in no position to make any recommendation.